# Existing li gets overridden in todolist instead of adding a new li

Tags: javascript

I am creating a Todolist, when I write something in the `input` and use the function `addNewFunc()` it adds a new `li`, the problem is that it always just overrides that `li`, it never makes a new `li`. (example: I write `1` in the `input`, use the function and `1` will be added as an `li`, if i write `2` in the `input` and use the function, that `1` will now become `2`, instead of having a `1` and `2`)

```js
let input = document.querySelector(".input");
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");    
let addNew = document.createElement("li");


let addNewFunc = function () {
  let name = ul.appendChild(addNew);
  name.textContent = input.value
};
```

```html
<h1>spooky</h1>


<input type="text" class="input">
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What happens if you move `let addNew = document.createElement("li");` inside the function? Most likely you're just reusing the same element over and over. If that line is in the function, you create a new element each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues.

1) Move `let addNew = document.createElement("li");` inside the function. When it's outside the function you're just reusing the same element over and over. If that line is in the function, you create a new element each time the function is called.

2) Might be worth changing that function expression to a function declaration so that it works better as I was picking up the following error in JSFiddle when I was testing the code:

> ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `addNewFunc' before initialization

```
let input = document.querySelector(".input");
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");
let button = document.querySelector('button');    
button.addEventListener('click', addNewFunc)

function addNewFunc() {
  let addNew = document.createElement("li");
  addNew.textContent = input.value;
  ul.appendChild(addNew);
};
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9v7tkj5j/4/)** (I added a button for convenience)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let input = document.querySelector(".input");
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");

let addNewFunc = function () {
  let addNew = document.createElement("li");
  addNew.innerHTML = input.value;
  let name = ul.appendChild(addNew);
};
```

```html
<h1>spooky</h1>
<input type="text" class="input"><button onclick='addNewFunc()'> add</button>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Create new `li` element everytime on the function call, add value to it then append to `ul` element.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have stored `ul` element in a variable, so you're appending new child at the same position (`ul` parent is not updated with information about new elements in it).

Try with:

```
let addNewFunc = function () {
  let name = document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(addNew);
};
```

Comment: Where's `addNew` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new li like this:

```
let addNewFunc = function () {
      var ul = document.getElementById("list");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("option string"));
      ul.appendChild(li);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Full code is

```
 let input = document.querySelector(".input");
 let ul = document.querySelector("ul");    
 input.onchange=function(){
    let addNew = document.createElement("li");
    addNew.innerHTML=this.value;
    this.value="";
    ul.appendChild(addNew);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help u.

**please note**: I have minute changes to your html; here u enter in inputbox and click button to add it to list

here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5o2vwdqc/

html

```
<h1>spooky</h1>


    <input type="text" class="input">
    <button id="addToList">
    Add to List
    </button>
    <ul id="theList">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
```

js

```
let input = document.querySelector(".input");
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");    
let addNew = document.createElement("li");

document.getElementById("addToList").onclick = function() {
  let inputValue = document.getElementsByClassName("input")[0].value;
  let addNew = document.createElement("li");
  let textNode = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  addNew.appendChild(textNode);
  document.getElementById("theList").appendChild(addNew);  
}
```